# A question on discrete group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a quotation below:

For a discrete group $\Gamma$ , $f\in l^{\infty}(\Gamma)$ and $s, t\in \Gamma$. We let $s.f \in l^{\infty}(\Gamma)$ be the function $s.f(t)=f(s^{-1}t)$.

My question is

**If $f\in l^{\infty}(\Gamma)$, then what is $f(t)$ here? I mean $f(t)=?$**

Comment: You can use \ell to get $\ell$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably used to think of $\ell^\infty(\Gamma)$ as the set of bounded sequences indexed by $\Gamma$. That's nothing but $$\{f:\Gamma\to\mathbb C:\ \sup\{|f(t)|:\ t\in \Gamma\}<\infty\}. $$

If you think about it $f_t$ is nothing but notation for $f(t)$.

Comment: As we know, $l^{\infty}(\Gamma)=\{\alpha=\{\alpha_{x}\}_{x\in \Gamma}: sup|\alpha_{x}|<\infty\}$, so do you mean $f(t)=\alpha_{t}$, $t\in \Gamma$?

Comment: I wouldn't use $\alpha$ and $f$ for the same object.

Comment: But I still do not know, in $\{f:\Gamma\to\mathbb C:\ \sup\{|f(t)|:\ t\in \Gamma\}<\infty\} $, what is $f(t)$ here?

Comment: $f(t)$ is a complex number; I'm really not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I think, here, $f$ should be an element in $l^{\infty}(\Gamma)=\{\alpha=\{\alpha_{x}\}_{x\in \Gamma}: sup|\alpha_{x}|<\infty\}$, how can we regard $f$ as an function on $\Gamma$ (it just a bounded sequence indexed by $\Gamma$)?

Comment: When you say "sequence", you are assuming that $\Gamma$ is countable, which it might not be. In any case, "bounded sequence indexed by $\Gamma$" is nothing but a funny way of saying "bounded function $\Gamma\to\mathbb C$".

Answer (score 0):

In your setting, $f$ is just a bounded function on the group with values in real or complex numbers. $f(t)$ is its value at $t$.